# Problem with reading string and its pattern? [python]

Tags: python, string, ascii

I am running a code on a fasta file (the structure is shown below). This file has multiple entries where the header (seq id) of the entries starts with the ">" sign. The following lines after the header is the actual entry.

```
>AF528955.1 Octopus vulgaris isolate 2 16S ribosomal RNA gene, partial sequence; mitochondrial gene for mitochondrial product
UAACUUAUCUUCUAAGCAAAAAACUUGGUUUAUUCUUCAACUAAACUCAAAAUUAAGGAAGUUAAUACAA
UACUUUAAAUUAAUUUUAUUCCUUGAUCACCCCAACCAAAGUUAUUUACAAAUAAAUUAUAUAUAUACAU
AUAUAUCUAUAUAAUAACA
>AF528954.1 Octopus vulgaris isolate 1 16S ribosomal RNA gene, partial sequence; mitochondrial gene for mitochondrial product
UAACUUAUCUUCUAAGCAAAAAACUUGGUUUAUUCUUCAACUAAACUCAAAAUUAAGGAAGUUAAUACAA
UACUUUAAAUUAAUUUUAUUCCUUGAUCACCCCAACCAAAGUUAUUUACAAAUAAAUUAUAUAUAUACAU
AUAUAUCUAUAUAAUAACA
```

What I am facing is that a part of the does not go through as expected. Here is the part where I always get the "NOTE" when running it on my fasta file.

```
def count_rrna_subunits(full_species_name, seq_filename):
    counts = {}
    with MultiSequenceFile(seq_filename, ignore_missing_file=True) as input_seqs:
        for seq_id, seq_desc, seq in input_seqs:
            m = re.search(rb'^([^0-9]+)_([0-9][^_]+)', seq_id)
            if m:
                species = m.group(1).replace(b'_', b' ')
                subunit = m.group(2)
                if species == full_species_name.encode('ascii'):
                    if subunit in counts:
                        counts[subunit] += 1
                    else:
                        counts[subunit] = 1
            else:
                print("NOTE: could not parse rRNA subunits information for entry:\n{}Reference rRNA subunit listing may be unavailable in miRTrace reports generated using this database. Actual read mapping not affected.\n".format(seq_id), file=sys.stderr)
    return counts
```

In my fasta file, the full_species_name is "Octopus vulgaris".

Based on my search I found that the error could be because of having strings instead of byte strings in the headers of the fasta file. I tried multiple ways to convert the headers to byte string but I was not successful and the Python code was giving the "NOTE" message again. I prefer not to change the big code since it is part of a tool but the fasta file header so it matches the Python code.

How can I solve this? Thank you.

Comment: Can't you match to a string pattern then?

Comment: `^` that is not in `[]` means start of the line - so it makes `^([^0-9]+)` part only catch `>AF` part in your descriptive lines. Then the pattern requires `_` (always, not optional) so it fails because next character is a digit. | Also, even if you remove `^` - the strings you showed us don't have `_` at all

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So would it make sense to have the headers as "Octopus_vulgaris_16S_ribosomal_RNA_gene_1" & "Octopus_vulgaris_16S_ribosomal_RNA_gene_2" & "Octopus_vulgaris_16S_ribosomal_RNA_gene_3" & so on??